# How to tell screenreader to read a toggled element

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, accessibility, wai-aria

Instead of adding/removing my different sections to/from the DOM, I'm only hiding them with `aria-hidden="true"`, and unhiding them if certain `<a>` toggles are clicked.

Reasons are performance and an easier noscript fallback. The order in the DOM is not the order in which the questions appear.

The result is a binary question tree (yes/no questions) in which the user clicks from one question to the next.

Now what would be a good solution to make screen readers read a section or at least continue reading it next after unhiding it?

Is there a way with `live-region`? Do screenreaders read elements that become unhidden in it? I thought `aria-current` might be appropriate? Or is it more an `aria-expanded` application?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are you removing them in the first place? If it's only to save screen real estate, you probably shouldn't be hiding them from screen readers at all.

Comment: @isherwood it's a Yes/No question tree, where one answer leads to the next question. Hence most of the questions in the DOM are irrelevant to your path in the tree.

Comment: This does not sound like a good application of live regions at all as the initial answer suggests because of the interactive nature.  Are you hiding the unused parts of the tree visually (e.g. with `visibility: off` or `display: none`)?  Please describe how this is displayed visually and how the user navigates from one question to the next.  For example, do the answered questions disappear after moving on?  If not, can I go back and change my answe way back at an earlier point in the tree, and what happens visually if I do?  A good answer can't be given without knowing this.

Comment: Only one question is visible at first (`display: none` and `aria-hidden=true`). When you answer Yes or No, the corresponding next question is shown below. The previous questions stays visible. At any point in time you can change your answer to any question, all following questions will be hidden then, and the corresponding next question appears (again). Always one question only is the active one.

Comment: https://www.mobility-service.org/en/assistent

Answer (score 1):

[ARIA live regions](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-live) are without question the correct way to handle this sort of problem.

By using the `aria-live` attribute on an HTML element, assistive technology will be alerted when content is changed in one of these areas. Your choice of attribute value will specify how quickly the change is announced (immediately, or at next graceful opportunity). The most common implementation is typically `aria-live="polite"`.

This page outlines some pretty useful (and innovative) techniques for implementing live regions: https://terrillthompson.com/tests/aria/live-scores.html

Comment: But I have it on `aria-live="assertive"`, and NVDA doesn't read anything when a new element becomes unhidden?

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample that I can test?

Comment: It just occurred to me! The updates aren't being announced because nothing is being added/removed from the DOM tree. Rather than using live regions, it may be better in this case to add `role="alert` to the elements when you change `aria-hidden` to false.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I will try that and get back to you.